# Replace duplicate values and repeat a combination in a column

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have the column 'state' in a data frame with values of "Buy", "Sell",and "NaN":

| No.Row | state | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | 10 |
| 2 | Sell | 20 |
| 3 | Buy | 10 |
| 4 | NaN | 5 |
| 5 | Buy | 6 |
| 6 | Buy | 30 |
| 7 | Sell | 50 |
| 8 | Sell | 25 |
| 9 | Buy | 40 |
| 10 | Buy | 35 |
| 11 | NaN | 10 |
| 12 | Sell | 5 |

I want to have the first "Buy" and then "Sell", respectively (Buy, Sell) .and then the value of "Sell"(now) - "Buy"(before) for "Reduction" column.
For example in the 7th row, we have 50(3th volumn)-10 (7th volumn)= 40
Desirable output:

| No.Row | state | Reduction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | Buy |  |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 | Sell | 40 |
| 8 |  |  |
| 9 | Buy |  |
| 10 |  |  |
| 11 |  |  |
| 12 | Sell | -35 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a `global` variable which would track the `last buy` state.

Then use a reduction method to compute cost each time you arrive at a `Sell` state.

```py
global last_buy
last_buy = None 


def reduction(row):
    global last_buy
    if row.state == "Sell" and last_buy is not None: 
        cost = row.price - last_buy
        last_buy = None
        return cost
    
    if row.state == "Buy" and last_buy is None: 
        last_buy = row.price


df["reduction"] = df.apply(reduction, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   state  price  reduction
0   NaN      10        NaN
1   Sell     20        NaN
2    Buy     10        NaN
3   NaN       5        NaN
4    Buy      6        NaN
5    Buy     30        NaN
6   Sell     50       40.0
7   Sell     25        NaN
8    Buy     40        NaN
9    Buy     35        NaN
10  NaN      10        NaN
11  Sell      5      -35.0
```

Comment: That's Ok. But the column of "State" is changed so. what should I do about that?